# Is there a reason for websites needing a username/password

Tags: html, authentication

Is there any reason a site login needs a username/password?  If an email address or cell number is supplied a text or email could be sent back at which point you would click on the link. Would this be enough to be considered authenticated by the site. Much like a password reset email/text, except you would be logedin instead.

Comment: This question should be  posted on UX or Software Enginnering platforms.

Comment: The answer to this question is opinion based, so it does not belong to SO as you will read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Some sites have that as one and only authentication method. Imagine, you want to log-in on your mobile device, device on which you do not have the e-mail setup, you can clearly see the annoyance generated by such login system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the correct forum to post this. 
But, usually an username gives more sense of "ownership" / sense of belonging to an account. 
Also for security reasons! I'd rather not give my personal email to everyone or in some places. 
And if they already ask my email, I would imply my username is the information other users have access to, and not necessarily my email.
e.g. a Forum / Payments / etc...